# ¿Cómo utilizar FontAwesome para insertar un icono con unicode en Java Swing?

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing, font-awesome, fuentes

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en `Java`, la cual requiere de una fuente de texto en específico `FA5FR400.otf`. Ya que esta aplicación sera utilizada en varios equipos; al estar la fuente dentro del proyecto el texto sera igual en todos los equipos.

La razón de utilizar `FontAwesome` es que contiene una gran cantidad de iconos que quiero utilizar en la aplicación, esto se hace a través del texto en unicode.

El **Problema es** que he tratado de instanciar una nueva fuente llamando la ruta de mi archivo `.otf` para poder utilizar el texto `unicode` y lo interprete al icono que quiero utilizar, pero esto no me ha funcionado.

Lo que quisiera saber es ¿Cómo puedo obtener el archivo que requiero utilizar para interpretar el texto unicode o Cómo trabajar con los iconos de `FontAwesome` para utilizarlos en mi aplicación?

Sitio [FontAwesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

[Utilizar FontAwesome en Escritorio](https://fontawesome.com/get-started/desktop).

> No quiero quiero instalar la fuente en los equipos, sino que sea leída desde el proyecto, esto es importante.

**Mapa del Proyecto**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Código Java**

```
    lblIconUser.setFont(new Font(getClass().getResource("/recursosSCE/FA5FR400.otf").getPath(), Font.BOLD, 12));
    lblIconUser.setText("f007");
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa *no me funciona*? ¿Usa otra fuente, se lanza una excepción...? Por favor dale a [edit] y añade más información para que te podamos ayudar

Comment: @PabloLozano ya he editado la pregunta y el planteamiento

Comment: El sitio de font awesoma se ha complicado mucho, de plano abrpi el css y bajé la fuente desde allí, si no se ve del mismo tamaño es por eso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que veo que tu proyecto está hecho en netbeans aprovecharé para adpatar la solución al GUI builder que trae y que técnicamente se llama [matisse](/questions/tagged/matisse).

Primeramente arrastramos un nuevo label al GUI Builder de nuestro `JFrame`, vamos a la ventana de propiedades y allí editamos la propiedad `text`.

En el asistente seleccionamos el dropdown y elegimos `Custom code`. Una vez allí ponemos el caracter que deseemos usar de font awesome. en nuestro caso `f007`, que representado como caracter unicode es `\uf007`.

[image: texto personalizado en JLabel desde GUI Builder de netbeans]

suponiendo que aún no lo hagas, bajas la fuente y la pones en el paquete que usabas para la fuente que te pidieron. En mi caso se llama `fa-regular-400.ttf`.

[image: ubicación de la fuente]

Ahora seleccionamos otra vez en el GUI builder nuestro `lblIconUser` y en la ventana de propiedades abrimos el tab `Code` y allí deberemos de agregar código
antes de que se cree y después de que se cree, para ello editamos primero `Pre-Creation Code` y ponemos lo siguiente

```
try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/recursosSCE/fa-regular-400.ttf")){
    Font fontAwesome = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
    fontAwesome = fontAwesome.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24f);
```

como te habrás dado cuenta el código no compilaría debido a que falta una llave así que editamos `Post-Creation Code` y le ponemos

```
    lblIconUser.setFont(fontAwesome);
}catch (IOException | FontFormatException exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace();
}
```

Esto nos pondrá en la parte no editable del código una creación de nuestro componente de la siguiente forma:

```
try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/recursosSCE/fa-regular-400.ttf")){
            Font fontAwesome = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            fontAwesome = fontAwesome.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24f);

            lblIconUser = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            lblIconUser.setFont(fontAwesome);
        }catch (IOException | FontFormatException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
```

que es lo que hubiéramos querido si lo hubiéramos hecho a mano.

el `try` que usamos se le conoce como *try con recursos* y siempre tiene la forma

```
try(recurso_que_se_debe_cerrar)
```

y Java se encargará de cerrarlo en el orden correcto por nosotros.
Respecto a lo demás, lo que hicimos fue cargar nuestro archivo y convertirlo en una fuente TrueType que solamente estará disponible en nuestra aplicación, específicamente para nuestro `JLabel`.

El código tras agregarle los imports queda como:

```
package login;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author ruslan.lopez
 */
public class FrnLogin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form FrnLogin
     */
    public FrnLogin() throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/recursosSCE/fa-regular-400.ttf")){
            Font fontAwesome = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            fontAwesome = fontAwesome.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 24f);

            lblIconUser = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            lblIconUser.setFont(fontAwesome);
        }catch (IOException | FontFormatException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        lblIconUser.setText("\uf007");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(62, 62, 62)
                .addComponent(lblIconUser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 303, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(35, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(132, 132, 132)
                .addComponent(lblIconUser, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 126, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(42, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrnLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrnLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrnLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrnLogin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    new FrnLogin().setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FrnLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                } catch (FontFormatException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FrnLogin.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblIconUser;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Y al ejecutarlo se verá así:

[image: aplicación corriendo con el icono mostrándose]

Comment: El `Font.Plain, 24f` que es lo que hace?

Comment: ` try(InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fonts/Font Awesome 5 Free-Solid-900.otf")){
            Font fontAwesome = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is);
            fontAwesome = fontAwesome.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 20);
            lblAlertIcon_Login = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            lblAlertIcon_Login.setFont(fontAwesome);
        }catch (IOException | FontFormatException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }` No me muestra el icono

Comment: `lblAlertIcon_Login.setText("\f071");` en otras fuentes si me toma la tipografía.